# CALayer Layout Animation

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, uiview, calayer

I have a view that has subviews alongside **sublayers**.

myView

```
    var myView1 : UIView!
    var myLayer1: CALayer
    
        override final func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

            myView1.center    = CGPoiont(x: self.bounds.midX, y: 64)
            myLayer1.position = CGPoiont(x: self.bounds.midX, y: 128)
        }

}
```

When the device is rotated, the `myView1` center change animates, but `myLayer1` abruptly change into the new position without animation.

Is there a way to make the CALayer position change animate for device rotation?

PS: I do have more than one sublayer in the real project, more than 20.

Comment: The `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is a `UIView`-level delegation method, `CALayer`s live in a bit different part of the world. Have you tried to add explicit animation to your layers? Here's Apple's example: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html

Comment: I have to run a CABasicAnimation for each sub layer?

Comment: @Gizmodo - it's difficult to answer questions in the abstract. Post enough code to clearly show what's happening, along with your description of what you **want** to happen.

Comment: Well OP details exactly that. Instead of 1 sub layer, I got many more.

Comment: You need to use `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")` to animate the position of layers.